# PHP and Flask compatibilities

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-2015

My PHP code doesn't seem to work. I try to either print a success symbol or failure symbol in my HTML page depending on a value which is set for now. Therefore, I used the following PHP code:

```
<?php

$statut= false;
if ($statut == true)
{ echo <img src="P:\dev\Helloworld\Projet\tcl\templates img\téléchargement 
 (2).jpg"width="50" height="50" />;}
else ($statut == false)
{ echo 'P:\dev\Helloworld\Projet\tcl\templates\img\téléchargement 
(3).jpg<br/>';}
 ?>
```

I use `Flask` as web-developement framework and `Visual Code` as editor. When I run the server, I don't have any error returned but it displays some of my PHP code and not the corresponding images.

Do I have to import a PHP module from `Flask`? I am kind of lost here.

Answer (score 0):

**Correct your syntax**

`if(..)` or `elseif(..)` can have conditions, but in your case you have for `else(..)` also

> The else statement is only executed if the if expression evaluated to
>   FALSE, and if there were any elseif expressions - only if they
>   evaluated to FALSE as well

**From**

```
if ($statut == true)
{ 
else ($statut == false){

}
```

**To**

```
if ($statut == true)
{

} 
else{

}
```